# Remove Traces of USB Devices ever connected to the computer

Tags: windows, usb, windows-registry

How to remove the USB Traces which ever connected to the computer?
I remove all entries from the registry "HLM/System/curentcontrolset/enum/usbstor" but unable to remove all entries from "HLM/System/curentcontrolset/enum/usb" and
"HLM/System/controlset001/enum/usb"
and
"HLM/System/controlset002/enum/usb".
How to remove that entries?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't do this by hand (as you are attempting to do).
There are windows hooks looking for device changes.. there are locks on those keys.. possible bad JUJU can happen..

1. Open a command prompt.
2. type `set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1`
3. Open the device manager by typing `devmgmt.msc`
4. Click on the 'view' menu item, then 'Show hidden devices'
5. Open the "Universal Serial Bus Controllers" node and delete the greyed out items.
6. Open the "Universal Serial Bus Devices" node and delete the greyed out items.

HECK!  While you are in here.. delete any of the old things you don't care about anymore. :)

Good luck!

Comment: It's easier to use USBDeview if you're deleting them by hand.  I would like a command line alternative, though.  (Oh wait it has command line options `/remove`. Not sure if it does the same thing as "Uninstall")

Comment: Thanks for the comment @endolith .. I too do not know if /remove does the same thing.  For USB specific items, I bet it works fine but the method I mentioned should work for any device.  Funny too.. I never got credit for this post :^P ..

Comment: It does the same thing as Uninstall

Comment: It is really hard to completely remove USB records. You can still find some records in the driver log and event logs. USBDeview is not effective.