# How to get rid of empty/phantom drives — like an Empty USB card reader — in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, usb-storage

I had this glitch earlier when connecting a USB-C hub with a Micro SD card and an Anker USB SD card reader with Micro SD card, it was when plugging both in with micro-sd cards, Windows File Explorer went crazy and started creating empty drives and I couldn't disconnect the drives, I wasn't able to access the Anker drive in particular it wouldn't load. Previously they never showed empty drives when nothing was connected but now if I plug in my Anker 2-port card reader (Micro SD and SD) if a slot is empty it shows up as an empty drive in File Explorer on Windows.

> [image: Empty Phantom Drives]

So the problem is that I know I can remove the drive letter assignments, but that means that if I plug something into the slot it will not appear in File Explorer until I manually re-assign it a drive letter. So that's not an option. I do not want to go back to not showing hidden folders/files or anything like that, the system worked fine with showing hidden items before, what I want is for the behaviour of these glitched card readers to return to normal where an empty sd slot does NOT show up as an empty drive. If I put a Micro SD card in the card reader I should only see the Micro SD card drive and not this:

> [image: Empty sd slot showing as empty drive]

I've done some testing and I've tried uninstalling the drivers for the USB-C hub and Anker card reader, then plugging it back in but that doesn't change anything. I've tried to delete the partition/volume but because there is no media in the slot it just gives a virtual disk error, nothing is in the drive so can't delete. My suspicion is that it has something to do with the driver because when I plugged it into my second Windows PC, it also shows the corrupt behaviour of displaying the empty disk. Wondering if anyone has seen this problem before?

Comment: See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1574914/remove-traces-of-usb-devices-ever-connected-to-the-computer) I wrote a long time ago.  It boils down to an environment variable `devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices ` coupled with using the `Show hidden devices`  menu option in the device manager.  Is this what you were looking for?  If not... is [THIS](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+phantom+drives+hide) what you are asking about?

Comment: Thanks I already uninstalled the USB device using USBDeview, it did not fix the problem. It's not just a random phantom drive the problem is that it is semi-legitimate as it's representing the slot for the removable media and the empty drives disappear when the card reader is removed from the PC. The thing is, my card readers never showed those empty drives before when plugged in, it would be just like plugging in a USB thumb drive only the one drive letter would appear.

Comment: So I can only assume that you have already tried the "Hide empty drives" setting in explorer settings?  I am not preaching.. just feeling around.  I have written more than ten windows shell extensions.. she and I are old friends.

Comment: My bad yes if I hide empty drives and Do not show hidden folders/files, they disappear but that shouldn't be necessary as I was showing hidden files before and the card readers worked fine, no empty hidden drives present before the glitch